# Caffe Installation: How to use libc++ instead of clang to power CUDA? (Mac)

Tags: cuda, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, nvcc, caffe

I know it dim-witted to do so, but I have to. 'Cause currently CUDA 7.0 doesn't support clang 7.0 while I'm using Xcode 7 beta, and it'll be virtually impossible for me to roll back to Xcode 6.0

```
NVCC src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cu
nvcc fatal   : The version ('70000') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported
make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/) for CUDA 7.0 states that for Mac OS X **Clang 6.0 (Xcode 6)** is the most recent supported version.

Comment: Alright, it seems virtually impossible to roll back to Xcode 6.0. So I wanna switch to link libc++ dependency to CUDA. But I cannot figure out how to do it, would you please give me some further advices?

Comment: @YiqunLiu I don't know what you mean by "switch to link libc++ dependency". It's probably better to ask a new question about that and close this one.

Comment: I confirm that latest CUDA version 7.5 does not support and works with XCode7.0. I'm running Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Instead of rolling back to Xcode 6 you can just install it alongside Xcode 7 by downloading an older release from Apple's [Developer Download Center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?name=Xcode). Give it a name different from Xcode 7's name (e.g. call it "Xcode 6.4") and they can live side by side without issue.

Just make sure you set the command line tools in your Xcode preferences to the older version when you want to compile with CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

## `nvcc` actual situation

`nvcc` is **parsed from a current clang binary version.**
e.g,

```
> export
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:/sbin

> clang -v
clang version 3.8.0 (git@github.com:llvm-mirror/clang.git
1082a41a5196e0fdddf1af1aa388af197cfc4514) (git@github.com:llvm
mirror/llvm.git 60fe48f86639ab4472d186bc97e7676f269cae18)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin

> make
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin clang++ -I../../common/inc  -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o asyncAPI.o -c asyncAPI.cu
nvcc fatal   : The version ('30800') of the host compiler ('clang') is not supported
Makefile:229: recipe for target 'asyncAPI.o' failed
make: *** [asyncAPI.o] Error 1
```

> nvcc fatal : The version ('30800') of the host compiler ('clang') is not supported

That means...?

```
> export PATH=/Applications/Xcode-6.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:/sbin

> CC=/usr/bin/clang CXX=/usr/bin/clang++ make
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin clang++ -I../../common/inc  -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o asyncAPI.o -c asyncAPI.cu
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin clang++   -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o asyncAPI asyncAPI.o
mkdir -p ../../bin/x86_64/darwin/release
cp asyncAPI ../../bin/x86_64/darwin/release
```

Success.
...However, unknown actually what nvcc are using the clang of CXX.

## Solution

So, Let's edit `clang` binary.

```
> cp /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang /tmp/clang

> cd /tmp

> vim ./clang
# or nvim, emacs, etc...

# Searching `700.1.75` and replace `602.0.53`.  
# In case of vim,
:%s/700.1.75/602.0.53/g
:wq

> export PATH=/tmp:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:/sbin

> wihch clang
/tmp/clang

> clang -v
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-602.0.53)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
# Faking clang version 602.0.53 (Xcode 6.4's clang)
# but, Actual implementation clang 7.0.0

> make
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin clang++ -I../../common/inc  -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o asyncAPI.o -c asyncAPI.cu
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin clang++   -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -o asyncAPI asyncAPI.o
mkdir -p ../../bin/x86_64/darwin/release
cp asyncAPI ../../bin/x86_64/darwin/release
```

Yeeeeees!
`nvcc` compiled using `clang version 7.0.0`.

In this way,

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-6.4.app/Contents/Developer
```

is **not** required.

## Be careful.

Now, Your `clang` is remains became `/tmp/clang`.

## FYI

My gist article,
[gist - How to compiling use CUDA nvcc with Xcode7.0 clang 7.0.0](https://gist.github.com/zchee/7833bf67013e83523181)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I'm guessing lot's more will since Xcode 7.0 is available on App Store now, was going to comment on Jay's but I dont have enough reputation.
What you can do instead of downloading the whole 5gb Xcode 6.x is check Xcode under

settings > locations > Command Line Tools

if there is an option to use 6.4 just switch to that.  If not, install *JUST* the command line tools 6.4 [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?name=Xcode) and then the option should be available.
The way he posted work's as well but then you need two versions of Xcode on your machine.

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't work (doesn't show up as an option)

Comment: @GatorCSE hmm odd, you installed the 6.4 tools and they didnt show up in the Xcode 7 settings?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what happened. They did install though, and I imagine that if I had more time to look into it then I could figure out how to get the right symlinks/variables set up, but I was able to get my project done with just the cpu.

Comment: @GatorCSE yep guessing we are all using theano and would like GPU ability though, hopefully someone smarter than me will post how so i don't have two versions of Xcode until Cuda updates